# Sobolev trace inequality with exterior domains

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

Let $x_1\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 3$, $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B_1(x_1)$, define $D_{\Omega}$ by taking the closure of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ under the norm
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{D_{\Omega}}:=\Big(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla  u|^2\Big)^{1/2}+\Big(\int_{\Omega}|u|^{2n/(n-2)}\Big)^{(n-2)/2n}.
\end{align*}
My question is  whether it is true for the following Sobolev trace inequality
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla \Phi|^2 \leq C(n,\Omega) \|\varphi\|_{H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial B_1(x_1))}^2
$$
for any $\Phi\in D_{\Omega}$ satisfying $$\Phi|_{\partial B_1(x_1)}=\varphi.$$
where $H^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the fractional space.

The paper [Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces] records that: for any $p \in(1,+\infty)$, assume that the open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is sufficiently smooth, then the space of traces $T u$ on $\partial \Omega$ of $u$ in $W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ is characterized by $\|T u\|_{W^{1-\frac{1}{p}, p}(\partial \Omega)}<+\infty$). Moreover, the trace operator $T$ is surjective from $W^{1, p}(\Omega)$.  I guess it has a similar result for the above inequality. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you take a non constant $\phi$ with support far away from the boundary, the trace is zero.

Comment: sorry， I can't follow your ideas，can you describe it more specifically?Thanks a lot

Comment: I am just saying that the inequality cannot hold: if you take $0 \neq \Phi$ with its trace $\phi=0$. Then you would get $\int |\nabla \Phi|^2=0$.